# Github action - Pushing flask application to docker hub

Tags: python, flask, github-actions

Blessings,

I made a Flask API application and whenever I try to push it to docker hub repository via GitHub Action it fails, Also when I try to run it using docker build/run the build finishes but says `This site can’t be reached`.

While when running the flask application locally (running python file) works.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR ./app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip firefox
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8777
CMD ["python3", "./simpleflask.py", "./main.py"]
```

I get the following error on Github :

```
Run docker build -t app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  76.29kB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.8
3.8: Pulling from library/python
e756f3fdd6a3: Already exists
bf168a674899: Already exists
e604223835cc: Already exists
6d5c91c4cd86: Already exists
2cc8d8854262: Already exists
2767dbfeeb87: Pulling fs layer
e5a387f746e4: Pulling fs layer
54b770283d3a: Pulling fs layer
d829066ff47d: Pulling fs layer
d829066ff47d: Waiting
54b770283d3a: Verifying Checksum
54b770283d3a: Download complete
2767dbfeeb87: Verifying Checksum
2767dbfeeb87: Download complete
e5a387f746e4: Verifying Checksum
e5a387f746e4: Download complete
d829066ff47d: Verifying Checksum
d829066ff47d: Download complete
2767dbfeeb87: Pull complete
e5a387f746e4: Pull complete
54b770283d3a: Pull complete
d829066ff47d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1fbd81716d6d8d6081b11b058894533e36c93abd10d91560ac8011a27ca13947
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.8
 ---> 050b8443e26e
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR ./app
 ---> Running in 6b66a93bccbb
Removing intermediate container 6b66a93bccbb
 ---> 784f3185eb08
Step 3/8 : COPY . /app
 ---> f1ba4f56f664
Step 4/8 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> 38014455957c
Step 5/8 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in c635f7bc6af6
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (22.0.4)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 50.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
    Uninstalling pip-22.0.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4
Successfully installed pip-22.1.2
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Removing intermediate container c635f7bc6af6
 ---> eac8515be6c0
Step 6/8 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 00790d0d61fb
Collecting Flask
  Downloading Flask-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 95.2/95.2 kB 16.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting Flask-RESTful
  Downloading Flask_RESTful-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
  Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.1/133.1 kB 23.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting importlib-metadata>=3.6.0
  Downloading importlib_metadata-4.11.4-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=2.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (224 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 224.9/224.9 kB 40.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting click>=8.0
  Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.6/96.6 kB 19.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting aniso8601>=0.82
  Downloading aniso8601-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 52.8/52.8 kB 12.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting six>=1.3.0
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 503.5/503.5 kB 47.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading zipp-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, aniso8601, zipp, Werkzeug, six, MarkupSafe, itsdangerous, click, Jinja2, importlib-metadata, Flask, Flask-RESTful
Successfully installed Flask-2.1.2 Flask-RESTful-0.3.9 Jinja2-3.1.2 MarkupSafe-2.1.1 Werkzeug-2.1.2 aniso8601-9.0.1 click-8.1.3 importlib-metadata-4.11.4 itsdangerous-2.1.2 pytz-2022.1 six-1.16.0 zipp-3.8.0
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Removing intermediate container 00790d0d61fb
 ---> 4d7bca1a1903
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Running in 5d1710cfff1f
Removing intermediate container 5d1710cfff1f
 ---> 2d116ca965c0
Step 8/8 : CMD ["python", "./simpleflask.py", "./main.py"]
 ---> Running in bebab646ec94
Removing intermediate container bebab646ec94
 ---> 881954660c46
Successfully built 881954660c46
Successfully tagged app:latest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0a6dc8e610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0a6dc8e610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = requests.post(url, json=(myobj, mysecobj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0a6dc8e610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I also hope its okay to post external links here but here's the repository
`https://github.com/awakzdev/Dockerized-API/`

## main.yml

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Script
        run: |
          docker build -t app .
          python ./main.py
          echo ${{ secrets.DOCKER.SECRET }} | docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER.USERNAME }} --password-stdin
          docker tag app awakz/
          docker push awakz/dockerized-flask
```

Comment: How are you pushing built image to docker hub ?

Comment: Also not sure why you are trying trying to run the server after built. Skip those steps and push to docker hub once built

Comment: @JishnuR I've edited the post with the main.yml

Comment: @JishnuR I was tasked with running it before pushing.

Comment: You cannot run python without setting up python on GHA. https://github.com/actions/setup-python

Comment: I've added python on GHA according to your guide and it still failed. I've changed the dockerfile image from ubuntu to python and it ran.. now flask takes up the whole terminal and wont let ./main.py run aftterwards, is there anyway to run it silently? https://i.imgur.com/YCPZEi4.png

Comment: Yeah im still not sure why you are running a server on GHA on merge. Once server runs it will wait there for request. GHA is not a place to run server. Build your image and push to dockerhub. Run your server containers on a place where its supposed to be run

Comment: @JishnuRamesh It was requested by my employer. an entrance exam for a devops job, anyway I had a problem logging in so I used `uses: docker/login-action@v2`